# Make parallel libcurl HTTP requests

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl, http-request

I have a question regarding the safety of performing parallel HTTP-requests using libcurl (C++). When reading this question, please bear in mind I have limited knowledge about HTTP-requests in general.

Basically, let's say I have two (or more) threads, each thread makes a HTTP-request once per second. (All the requests made are to the same server). How does my program (or something else?) keep track of what HTTP-response belongs to which tread? I mean, can I be sure that if request A was sent from thread 1, and request B from thread 2 at the same time, and the responses are retrived at the same time, the correct reponse (response A) goes to thread 1 and response B to thread 2?

Please excuse my ignorance in this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First of all libcurl is [thread safe](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/features.html#thread):

> libcurl is designed and implemented entirely thread safe

As pointed out by this official documentation all you need to do is:

> **Never** share libcurl handles between multiple threads. You should only use one handle in one single thread at any given time.

In addition there is also this [official FAQ entry](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Is_libcurl_thread_safe) that provides some more precisions, e.g if you plan to use SSL:

> If you use a OpenSSL-powered libcurl in a multi-threaded environment, you need to provide one or two locking functions

As you can see there is an official example which illustrates a multi-threaded use of the easy handles: see [multithread.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html):

```
/* This is the callback executed when a new threads starts */
static void *pull_one_url(void *url)
{
  CURL *curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
  curl_easy_perform(curl); /* ignores error */ 
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

  return NULL;
}

/* ... */

/* This is the main loop that creates `NUMT` threads for parallel fetching */
for(i=0; i< NUMT; i++) {
    error = pthread_create(&tid[i],
                           NULL, /* default attributes please */ 
                           pull_one_url,
                           (void *)urls[i]);
  /* ... */
}
```

So feel free to give this example a try.

At last keep in mind that libcurl also provides a so-called [multi interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) which *offers multiple transfers using a single thread*. You may find it convenient too according to your use case.

**EDIT**

Regarding OpenSSL + multi-threads there are specific official examples that might help:

- [opensslthreadlock.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/opensslthreadlock.html)
- [threaded-ssl.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threaded-ssl.html)

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. I have a bit of a problem understanding this: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html#DESCRIPTION  I don't have any openssl.h headers, I downloaded a pre-compiled binary, v0.9.8r for Win64-bit. Do you have an example of this? Thanks again.

Comment: I would say this deserves a (new) dedicated question.

Comment: Please see my answers below.

Comment: @ deltheil I will move this to a new question.