# Using libcurl unsuccessfully with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl

I'm trying to make use of libcurl with multiple threads. While reading the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html), I understood the correct way of doing it is to use a single `CURL*` handle for each thread.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

bool KeyIsValid(std::string keytocheck) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string content;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/mypage.php");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ("something=hello&somethingtwo=" + keytocheck).c_str());
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        // std::cout << content << std::endl;
        if (content.find("id or key is not correct") == std::string::npos) // if i use an != the correct key (abc) doesn't get printed
        {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing this code, I can say I'm working in a new handle for each thread. It makes the request to my *localhost* and, after the post request is performed, using a callback I'm storing the content to a `std::string`.
After everything I check if the webpage contains some identifiers for in/corrected id/key. Exactly, the page prints out this:

```
id or key is not correct
```

when the id/key is not correct. This is how I call the method `KeyIsValid()`:

```
if (KeyIsValid(currentKey))
        {
            std::cout << "key tested with success -> " << currentKey << '\n';
            return 1; // 1 = success
        }
```

but while I check every key stored in an array (1 stored key in the array equals to 1 new thread), I get some "misinterpretations":

```
key tested with success -> abc
key tested with success -> hello
key tested with success -> hello
key tested with success -> hello
```

while the only correct key is only `abc`. I'm not sure why the program prints the correct key `abc` followed from the other incorrect keys.
But if I change the array's items to just two items (`abc` and `hello`, and so using two threads), everything seems to work properly as I get printed just the `abc` key.

I did some searches in internet, this is [what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695666/make-parallel-libcurl-http-requests):

> I have a question regarding the safety of performing parallel HTTP-requests using libcurl (C++). When reading this question, please bear in mind I have limited knowledge about HTTP-requests in general. Basically, let's say I have two (or more) threads, each thread makes a HTTP-request once per second. (All the requests made are to the same server). How does my program (or something else?) keep track of what HTTP-response belongs to which tread? I mean, can I be sure that if request A was sent from thread 1, and request B from thread 2 at the same time, and the responses are retrived at the same time, the correct reponse (response A) goes to thread 1 and response B to thread 2? Please excuse my ignorance in this matter. Thanks.

this guy is just asking my same question *without being more specific* (he didn't show any code).

I'm going to exactly ask this:

> Can I be sure that if request A was sent from thread 1, and request B from thread 2 at the same time, and the responses are retrived at the same time, the correct reponse (response A) goes to thread 1 and response B to thread 2?

with reference to my code. Maybe I'm analyzing the page incorrectly, I don't know.

Sorry for my ignorance in this matter.

**Edit:**

- After two days I tried to change my callback code, but still nothing works properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I be sure that if request A was sent from thread 1, and request B
>   from thread 2 at the same time, and the responses are retrieved at the
>   same time, the correct response (response A) goes to thread 1 and
>   response B to thread 2?

Yes you can be **absolutely** sure of that.

Comment: Okay, if yes, what's answer that would explain the behavior of the program?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough detail to know that. I do know how libcurl works internally though.