Curl segmentation fault in multithreading
CURL version is 8.1.0. OS Ubuntu
void HttpClient::processingPutQuery(CURL *handle, SHttpPut *httpQuery, const char * error)
{
...
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, httpQuery->data_.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)httpQuery->data_.size());
ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, " (%P|%t) %N:%l The query text:\n %s\n", httpQuery->data_.c_str()));
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeData);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &httpQuery->answer());
CURLcode c = curl_easy_perform(handle);

....

    if(headers) {
        curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    }

    httpQuery->answerAccepter_->setVariable(true);
}


If I tried to call several times get query, I got core dump from curl library
#0  __memcpy_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S:1095
#1  0x000000000042a06a in std::char_traits<char>::copy (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
__s1=0x7a29360cd028 "", __s2=0x7a29b6b8d710 "\340j", __n=4376158) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:352
#2  0x000000000042a564 in std::string::_M_copy (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
__d=0x7a29360cd028 "", __s=0x7a29b6b8d710 "\340j", __n=4376158) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:3382
#3  0x0000000000430a6e in std::string::_Rep::_M_clone (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
this=0x7a29b6b8d6f8, __alloc=..., __res=17) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc:1081
#4  0x000000000044ad7e in std::string::reserve (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
this=0x7a29b6b8d6f0, __res=4376175) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc:960
#5  0x000000000044af22 in std::string::append (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
this=0x7a29b6b8d6f0, __s=0x7a297400b2f0 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n", __n=17) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc:758
#6  0x000000000064ad57 in HttpClient::writeData (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
buffer=0x7a297400b2f0 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n", size=1, nmemb=17, userp=0x7a29b6b8d6f0) at /home/dfuser/projects/dfr2024.2/dfr/service/httpClient.cpp:1002
#7  0x00007a29c32a109b in Curl_client_write () from /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
#8  0x00007a29c328abe0 in Curl_http_readwrite_headers () from /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
#9  0x00007a29c32b2518 in Curl_readwrite () from /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
#10 0x00007a29c3299396 in multi_runsingle () from /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
#11 0x00007a29c329a825 in curl_multi_perform () from /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
#12 0x00007a29c327840b in curl_easy_perform () from /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
#13 0x00000000006495f6 in HttpClient::processingGetQuery (Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing: 
this=0x7ffc0da9d9c8, handle=0x7a2974002cc0, httpQuery=0x7a297000a3a0, error=0x7a29b6b8d840 "") at /home/dfuser/projects/dfr2024.2/dfr/service/httpClient.cpp:811

In the callback function userp was reallocated or deleted. Vallgrind shows:
==4623== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==4623==    at 0x4836EAB: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4623==    by 0x42A605: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:125)
==4623==    by 0x42A4DF: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.tcc:899)
==4623==    by 0x42A3FD: std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.h:3270)
==4623==    by 0x44AD9F: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:961)
==4623==    by 0x64AA65: HttpClient::writeData(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, void*) (httpClient.cpp:986)
==4623==    by 0x6D3109A: Curl_client_write (in /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4)
==4623==    by 0x6D1ABDF: Curl_http_readwrite_headers (in /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4)
==4623==    by 0x6D42517: Curl_readwrite (in /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4)
==4623==    by 0x6D29395: multi_runsingle (in /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4)
==4623==    by 0x6D2A824: curl_multi_perform (in /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4)
==4623==    by 0x6D0840A: curl_easy_perform (in /home/dfuser/myproj/support/libcurl.so.4)
==4623==  Address 0x100c9618 is 24 bytes before a block of size 4,216 alloc'd
==4623==    at 0x483607F: operator new(unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

My callback function:
size_t HttpClient::writeData(char  *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) 
{   
    if ((size <= 0) || (nmemb <= 0) || (userp == NULL)) {
        return 0;
    }
    try
    {
        std::string *answer = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(userp);
        nmemb*=size;
        const std::size_t answerLen = answer->length();  // ----> here answerLen is very big  
        if (answer->length() < nmemb)
        {
            answer->reserve(answer->length() + nmemb);
        }
        answer->append(buffer, nmemb);     // ---> here segmentation is fault. 
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc &e)
    {
        ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, " Bad alloc: %s\n", e.what()));
    }
    return nmemb;
}

how can you solve this ? Is it library error?
Segmentation fault also happen with local variable:
CURL version is 8.1.0. OS Ubuntu
void HttpClient::processingPutQuery(CURL *handle, SHttpPut *httpQuery, const char * error)
{
...
string answer;
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, httpQuery->data_.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)httpQuery->data_.size());
ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, " (%P|%t) %N:%l The query text:\n %s\n", httpQuery->data_.c_str()));
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeData);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &answer);
CURLcode c = curl_easy_perform(handle);

....

    if(headers) {
        curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    }

    httpQuery->answerAccepter_->setVariable(true);
}


Also I tried to set local object as third parameter of callback function. And I got segmentation failure error, same situation. And here no destructor of object was called...
Curl should be thread safe.
There are 2 servers that communicate with each other.
Queries can be between GUI and main server and main server -> second server. Main server is performing some multi-thread tasks. Also I tried to use GUI in this moment to get information from main server. And I got curl crash.
Headers are created for every HttpQuery class's object.
Every HttpQuery object is waiting curl task finish. Every HttpQuery is alive, otherwise we cannot send any curl query initially. But in callback function HttpQuery member object was reallocated.
Thank you!

It's most likely a bug in the code that you have written however I don't think you have shown enough code.

Side notes. The condition length() < nmemb is wrong and is not necessary at all, because you don't need to call reserve before append. You don't need reinterpret_cast from a void pointer, static_cast is valid there.

reinterpret_cast should work as static_cast. It is not a cause of segmentation fault. Also reserve() function is not cause of  segmentation fault. The pointer was already reallocated. In my case  length() < nmemb is not performaed. Because length() is very big.

@drescherjm why? It perfectly works in same thread. But it does not work in multithread.

You may want to look into tools like address sanitizer and thread sanitizer to help you pinpoint the exact cause of the problem. Also see What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?. Side note: Multithreading is hard / difficult!

A [mre] instead of code pieces should be posted. And please don't argue when you get (good) advices. The very big length is a clear sign of invalid memory access - likely a dangling pointer to a destroyed object. If you convert the length to hex you likely see some pattern of a bad memory like DEDEDEDE

@ЭльфияВалиева "reinterpret_cast should work as static_cast" - No. They are not the same thing and the guarantees you get from the language about what you can do with a reinterpret_cast'ed thing is not at all the same as what you can do with a static_cast'ed thing. reinterpret_cast is almost always a sign that you are doing it wrong (just like C-style casts).

@JesperJuhl BUT reinterpret_cast is NOT cause of segmnentation fault. It is not this discussion theme. That all. I know that is reinterpret_cast . I don't write this code, I tried to fix someone code.

reinterpret_cast is NOT cause of segmnentation fault It is not particularly here, but the code style shows the all code may be full of bugs. Finally, we discuss in comments what you show. We can't fix a bug in the not shown code.

@ЭльфияВалиева "BUT reinterpret_cast is NOT cause of segmnentation fault" - You say that, but I'm not so sure. std::string *answer = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(userp); looks very much like undefined behaviour to me - and UB could very easily result in a segfault (or anything  else for that matter).

I respectfully suggest a visit to The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List.

@JesperJuhl Also I used static_cast, then try use local object as callback function 3rd parameter. I had segmentation fault.

@ЭльфияВалиева You cannot just take an arbitrary void* and cast to a std::string* and then expect it to behave as if it's a pointer to a std::string. The void* could be pointing to whatever and a cast is not some magical "transform this thing into that other thing". Casts just don't work that way - there will be no conversion of one thing into another thing, only a reinterpretation of the bytes making up "the thing" as if it was "some other thing" and if that new interpretation is not valid, then your program will fall flat on its face..

@JesperJuhl thank you, ok, I will changed and try again. Thank you! And why not? It is callback function  signature. It worked in one thread. Also called thread safe function from curl curl_multi_perform ()

@JesperJuhl curls is thread safe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695666/make-parallel-libcurl-http-requests You are wrong too

&httpQuery->answer() is probably a pointer to something that you believe will be a std::string.  When that pointer becomes a dangling pointer can't be answered with the limited code you are showing here.  But the core dump certainly seems to indicate that on line 1002 of your httpClient.cpp file it is dangling.

@DrewDormann It is callback functon, it is a member of class httpClient. I added callback function realization

Side note: if ((size <= 0) makes no sense since size is of type size_t which can't be negative.

@JesperJuhl Please, STOP refactoring this code. Lets try to solve segmentation fault error. Theme about that.

curls is thread safe Don't stop at the title, continue reading: "libcurl is thread safe but has no internal thread synchronization."

@ЭльфияВалиева As long as the code contains UB it doesn't make sense to try and reason about it. It could result in a segfault, it could do nothing at all or it could do exactly what you expected. but it is all wrong.

Are you using the same cURL handle from multiple threads? Because the address in userp (0x7a29b6b8d6f0) is nowhere near the stack address of the function that called curl_easy_perform (0x7a29c327840b) despite userp being the address of a stack variable local to that frame. Which leads me to suspect it is actually part of another thread's stack. A thread apply all bt at the point of crashing will produce stack traces of all threads, including the one this thread is scribbling over.

tl;dr: don't share curl handles across threads. They're cheap to create.
